# Haskell-Raytracer camera definition - flipped y-Axis

Tags: math, haskell, camera, coordinates, raytracing

I have a question regarding to the camera implementation for a simple raytracer. Until now I've implemented the coordinate axis of the view plane like this

```
constructAxes :: Position -> LookAtVec -> UpVec -> Axes
constructAxes pos lookAt up = (xAxe, yAxe, zAxe)
where zAxe = normalise $ pos `sub` lookAt
      xAxe = normalise $ zAxe `cross` up
      yAxe = normalise $ xAxe `cross` zAxe
```

to get a ([1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,-1]) system. But it turns out that this configuration leads to a flipped y-Axis (positive values move an object along the negative y-Axis). So I changed the definition for the y-Axe

```
yAxe = normalise $ xAxe `cross` vnegate zAxe
```

But why do I have to do this? My lecture materials and some other resources don't mention such a problem.

My second problem has to do with the intersection of an infinite plane. When I want to get the right result, I have to define the plane's normal with `[0,-1,0]` although from my point of view it has to be `[0,1,0]` (but then it looks like that the whole plane is also inverted in y-direction). Is that a consequence from the descriped camera definition?

I'd appreciate some hints.

Meiner

PS: This is the relevant code from the program: http://lpaste.net/1844512493116850176

Comment: Just guessing because I don't know what the rest of your code looks like: on a monitor, y = 0 is usually the topmost row and y increases towards the bottom of the screen; opposite of the y axis as commonly used in mathematics.

Comment: I know that defintition from working with OpenGL, but do I have to mention that in this case too? I mean, I only create a .ppm file and dont use any APIs, so from my pov I have the full control about my coordinate system (and I want it to work in a mathematical correct way). I added a link to my code if that helps.

Comment: Your code is missing the image saving code, but a common mistake in ray tracers lies in the image saving part. As Jesper mencioned, monitors and images have the y axis inverted from what you expect from mathematics. You can save the `height - coordinate` pixel instead of `coordinate`, and that should save correctly.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at the image saving code. I added the code in the link above (which is basically from here: https://github.com/ryanl/haskell-raytracer/blob/master/src/Image.hs)

Comment: I flipped the y-axis in the image generation and now I can use the "correct" axis-definitions from my 1. try. Thanks for this hint.
But I still have the problem with the defition of the infinite plane normal in a basic setup (it has to be [0,-1,0], but isn't [0,1,0] right?). Maybe heres something wrong with my intersection code (see link above)?